# How to copy data of any object from one language to other language in pimcore 5?

Tags: pimcore-v5

I have to copy data of any object which is localized. I want to copy English data in the new locale whenever i add a new language. e.g. If i am adding a new language Germany then the English data of this particular object should be copied in German too.

Comment: Make a background process where first list all the objects and explicitly set the values in the desired language. For eg $object->setValue($object->getValue("en"), "de")

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you won't like to use fallback Pimcore functionality? https://pimcore.com/docs/5.x/Development_Documentation/Multi_Language_i18n/index.html#page_Language-Configuration

If you'll use it you won't need to copy data but when Pimcore will see that German language is empty then **the fallback logic** will use English data